# Finding levels/subsets that will predict labels with high probabilty

Tags: r, correlation, mathematical-statistics, conditional-probability

Assume some 1000 data-points of the following pattern

```
X1 X2 Y
2  B  1
1  C  0
6  A  0
3  B  1
3  C  0
```

where $X_1 \in \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$, $X_2 \in \{A, B, C\}$ and the labels $Y \in \{0,1\}$

Now, for example, I observe that whenever `X1` is 2, 3, or 4 and `X2` is B at the same time, `Y` is almost always 1. So $Pr(Y=1|X_1 =\{2,3,4\}, X_2=B)$ is going to be higher.

How can I find such observations (mathematically) in `R`? The objective is to find such key values that will help create buckets to classify new data-points into. If not a coding solution, I would also appreciate any suggestions in best approach to take.

Here's some code to generate a sample data frame ...

```
set.seed(123)
X1 <- sample (1:6, 1000, rep = TRUE)
X2 <- sample(c('A', 'B', 'C'), 1000, rep = TRUE)
Y <- sample(c(0, 1), 1000, rep = TRUE)
df <- data.frame(X1, X2, Y)
```

Comment: I can't come up with an appropriate title, please feel free to edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach would be to derive this information from looking at a tree based model trained on your data.

The tree would be grown trying to obtain more homogeneous groups of samples for which it can correctly predict `Y`, while the tree complexity is limited using e.g. pruning (to not overfit or simply remember all samples). The obtained, final tree essentially divides your feature space into multiple (possibly rectangular) subspaces - therefore this is one form of grouping samples with regard to `Y`. Samples within one group = subspace will have a relatively high/low probability of `Y==0` resp. `Y==1`, which should account for the probability you mentioned.

I would try using such an approach (e.g. first with a simple CART, and if it works with more complex models, possibly model trees or J48/C5.0 etc.), and try to regulate the tree complexity using pruning and similar techniques. Thereby, you should be able come up with a tree that is still small enough for your needs (small number of terminal nodes), but also has at least some terminal nodes with sufficient probabilities for `Y==0` or `Y==1` - which would essentially be the groups you are searching for.

Comment: +1, I think a tree-based model is definitely the way to go here.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly use simple feature correlation (`?cor`) for this, which is based on the features' covariance. If this is an option for you, you could simply create one-hot encoded dummy variables out of your factors:

```
> library(caret)
> df2 <- data.frame(predict(dummyVars(~., df), df))
> str(df2)

> str(df2)
'data.frame':   1000 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ X1  : num  2 5 3 6 6 1 4 6 4 3 ...
 $ X2.A: num  1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 ...
 $ X2.B: num  0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 ...
 $ X2.C: num  0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 ...
 $ Y   : num  0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 ...
```

Using such data with `cor`, you would end up with e.g. such information:

```
> library(corrplot)
> myCor <- cor(df2)
> print(myCor)

              X1        X2.A         X2.B        X2.C            Y
X1    1.00000000  0.05282849 -0.034155072 -0.01812134  0.035527106
X2.A  0.05282849  1.00000000 -0.517131108 -0.47597892 -0.010821102
X2.B -0.03415507 -0.51713111  1.000000000 -0.50658893 -0.005726481
X2.C -0.01812134 -0.47597892 -0.506588926  1.00000000  0.016784564
Y     0.03552711 -0.01082110 -0.005726481  0.01678456  1.000000000    

> corrplot(myCor)
```

[image: Correlation plot]

Comment: I did exactly this, but this doesn't give me a combination of some subset of X1 and level of X2 that will give me a high probability of getting Y = 1.

Comment: True. I guess I misunderstand your goal before. Intuitively, you could e.g. derive this information from looking an a tree based model created from your data, as those divide samples into more homogeneous groups (which should be one solution to your question). Would this be helpful?

Comment: Lots of nodes on the tree, but that might get me somewhere. Could I try some sort of cost based optimisation technique, perhaps?

Comment: @Aayush Yes, pruning should do this in your case. I'll try to formulate a (short) second answer ;)